Could Marsupials evolve to be bigger than terrestrial placentals?
One factor that limits placentals from getting bigger than paleoloxodon is their mode of reproduction. Marsupials don't have the same problem as they gave birth to lots of underdeveloped joeys, if by chance they're able to expand to big herbivore niches, could they get bigger than paleoloxodon and if so what other adaptation would they need to achieve it?

I think you have already answered your question in the question itself when you state the limitation of marsupials when compared to placentals.

Remember the brachiosaurs spent much of their time in water for a reason. The square-cube law applies no matter the method of reproduction.

"They gave birth to lots of underdeveloped joeys": Maybe some do, I don't know; but the iconic red kangaroo gives birth to one underdeveloped joey, who the proceeds to spend about six months in the pouch during which time no other joey is produced.

@Escapeddentalpatient. brachiosaurus did not spend any time in the water, swamps would be a great way to kill a brachiosaurus.

The dinosaur book I had as a child must have been very old. I'll make a point of putting it in a museum. @John

Given that there have been examples of large animals from many branches of the tree of life what makes you think that there is something special about marsupials?

@tor desac  Not sure why you believe that marsupials couldn't become as large as paleoloxodon given the right environment. That is i why do you believe that reproduction mode has significant impact on maximum size compared to the mechanical structure of bones muscles etc, food availability and other factors.

The only limitations to marsupial size are food supply, predation, and physics. They absolutely could and maybe did grow as big as any terrestrial mammal.
